# FeedbackPanel for nested Form

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.6

Is it possible to catch a nested form submit for rendering its feedback panel?

---

More specifically:

I have an outer form with a feedback panel and an inner form with a feedback panel. The outer form is submitted via an AjaxButton. Within the button's onError method I add the feedback panel to the AjaxRequestTarget.

But this "outer" feedback panel shows also the inner form's validation messages. I would like to add the inner form's feedback panel with its validation messages. But I can't find any way how to catch the inner form submit event.

Answer (score 0):

You should use FencedFeedbackPanel for this.

Comment: Yes, but how? Where to add this feedback panel? In the inner panel containing the inner form, I don't know how to recognize it has been submited.

Comment: I think it should be enough to add the 'inner form' to the request target so it gets rerendered on the submit of the outer form.